# Sorting a mixed array of hashes and strings

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash

What is the syntax for sorting an array alphabetically by the key of a hash or by a string? I would like to sort the following:

```
['bob', 'apple', 'sandwich', {'lasagne' => 'munch'}, 'tangoed']
```

to give the following:

```
['apple', 'bob', {'lasagne' => 'munch'}, 'sandwich', 'tangoed']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear what to do when a hash includes more than one key. Considering always the first key in a hash:

```
['bob', 'apple', 'sandwich', {'lasagne' => 'munch'}, 'tangoed']
.sort_by{|e| [*e].flatten.first}
#=> ["apple", "bob", {"lasagne"=>"munch"}, "sandwich", "tangoed"]
```

Comment: Hi Sawa thanks for your answer, could you tell me what the [*e] part does before the flatten?

Comment: If `to_a` is defined (which is the case for hashes), then it applies `to_a` to it, remove the `[]` surrounding it, and surrounds it with another `[]`. Otherwise (which is the case for strings), it surrounds it with `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just translate your words into symbols:

```
arr = ['bob', 'apple', 'sandwich', {'lasagne' => 'munch'}, 'tangoed']

arr.sort_by { |e| e.is_a?(String) ? e : e.keys.first }
  #=> ["apple", "bob", {"lasagne"=>"munch"}, "sandwich", "tangoed"]
```